# Disjoint Union in Flow not being "disjointed"

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am having some issues trying to use the "[disjoint unions](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#disjoint-unions-a-classtoc-idtoc-disjoint-unions-hreftoc-disjoint-unionsa)" created by flow. Apparently flow tries to mash them together, but I still don't actually know why.

```js
type Single = {|
  type: 'single',
  value?: string,
  onChange: (value?: string) => void,            // line:47
|};

type Multiple = {|
  type: 'multiple',
  value?: string[],
  onChange: (value: string[]) => void,           // line:53
|}
type Props = Single | Multiple;
```

Having the flow definitions from above, I should be able to do this without any error, right?

```js
// (Yes, it is react)
function someFunc(receivedValues?: string[]) {
  // ...
  // value, type and onChange were pulled from "props: Props"

    if (type === 'single') {
      if (receivedValues && receivedValues.length) {
        onChange(receivedValues[0]);                     // line:110
      }
    } else if (type === 'multiple') {
      if (receivedValues && receivedValues.length) {
        const casted: string[] = value && value.length ? value : [];
        onChange(casted.concat(receivedValues));         // line:115
      }
    }

  //...
}
```

But flow throws me multiple errors:

```
Error: file.jsx:110
110:   onChange(receivedValues[0]);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ string. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
 53:   onChange: (value: string[]) => void,
                         ^^^^^^^^ array type

Error: file.jsx:114
114:   const casted: string[] = value && value.length ? value : [];
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ string. This type is incompatible with
114:   const casted: string[] = value && value.length ? value : [];
                     ^^^^^^^^^^ array type

Error: file.jsx:115
115:   onChange(casted.concat(receivedValues));
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ array type. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
 47:   onChange: (value?: string) => void,
                          ^^^^^^^ string
```

For what I understand it is just merging `Single` and `Multiple`, and it is not making the selection of one of them. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Since you've pulled the values off of the object already, checking `type` has no effect on narrowing down the type of `value` and `onChange`. Your code will work if you work with the object directly:

```
function someFunc(receivedValues?: string[]) {
  var obj: Props = { type: 'single', onChange: () => {} };

  if (obj.type === 'single') {
    if (receivedValues && receivedValues.length) {
      obj.onChange(receivedValues[0]);
    }
  } else if (obj.type === 'multiple') {
    if (receivedValues && receivedValues.length) {
      const casted: string[] = obj.value && obj.value.length ? obj.value : [];
      obj.onChange(casted.concat(receivedValues));
    }
  }
}
```

([On Flow playground](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwDKAlgHYDmM+AvGAN4A+qYYWeAXGAOQDOpFunADRMwANwCGMAK64A-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-u1uG4lksFdNIhmoSAA))

or only destructure the values off the object after refining the type.

```
function someFunc(receivedValues?: string[]) {
  var obj: Props = { type: 'single', onChange: () => {} };

  if (obj.type === 'single') {
    const { onChange } = obj;
    if (receivedValues && receivedValues.length) {
      onChange(receivedValues[0]);
    }
  } else if (obj.type === 'multiple') {
    const { onChange, value } = obj;
    if (receivedValues && receivedValues.length) {
      const casted: string[] = value && value.length ? value : [];
      onChange(casted.concat(receivedValues));
    }
  }
}
```

([On Flow playground](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwDKAlgHYDmM+AvGAN4A+qYYWeAXGAOQDOpFunADRMwANwCGMAK64A-B27oATn2HM4JAMIALceVwcAFBOlyFyvgEowVAHxi4RACaDmb92+DAwMUgYAsAOyo9AC+ANyoGDj4ALJSMOhE2JQ2dIzMrAZcALYJSSkCamKSMvJgiirkANoAusUaOnpk2cal2ZV8ddZ2Ds6uHh5ePn5sAKwAzCGh0XhgAApKcNjcacTkqfRg8YnJlJFRUFIkAMZJGhVwObgAYscnhkq4J7hEorhOAGrt3OWdNbVrLQRBIlGA4AAjABWHEWy1WNFoLBiHB4fEoQnBWl0+iMPXstFCYAiUWYRCgYEMkKhADosjYqDQ0RsBECRMwThpFHQsU19MS0tTIu5yZSni83h9vqZVgAyWVgcWvd5fH40yjkdDaNmDRo4lqPZ7KqU-aoABkBwrcM2YRNwMG4+FFVOhdJiDKZeV2hU4OrcnJI3KReuauFcJhkApoQvZYGdSslqplYHliqNielMm46twmu1dFjHK56DAJ3Eig+5iqZDqaQj+FT9ZzebAshKpjAHDqVvcIf0hjLFacNIDZfQholKszuG4lksPeJIhmoSAA))